# Problems with material while exporting model to Substance Painter from Blender

Tags: materials, export

I made the model in Blender. I also made a UV map for the model. The problem is that in Substance Painter for several parts the material does not work and Substance Painter creates a new one.
[image]

Therefore, my model is now divided into 2 materials

[image]

For example, a small ring has disappeared in this place because it has moved to a new material. And so holes appeared in several places.

[image]

In Blender, everything is displayed normally and belongs to the same material.
[image]

[image]

Which I have already done:
I checked the normals, unwrapped the model again, checked that the model was monolithic, and tried to export with different settings.

Blender file here:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this happened, but I selected all the meshes, chose the material, and clicked *Assign*. The problem was solved.